# issues with bootstrap 3 complex form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have following form with multiple inputs

```
        <form>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                <div class="col-md-8">filename: teamA_vs_teamB.mvd, map: ztndm3</div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4">TeamA</div>
                <div class="col-md-4">TeamB</div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                <div class="col-md-1">name</div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="p1_name">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="p2_name">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="p3_name">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="p4_name">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="p5_name">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="p6_name">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="p7_name">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="p8_name">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            </div>
            </br>
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">frags</div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="p1_frags">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="p2_frags">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="p3_frags">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="p4_frags">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="p5_frags">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="p6_frags">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="p7_frags">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="p8_frags">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                </div>
            </br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                <div class="col-md-1">deaths</div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="p1_deaths">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="p2_deaths">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="p3_deaths">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="p4_deaths">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="p5_deaths">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="p6_deaths">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="p7_deaths">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="p8_deaths">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Process</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

My problem is that it doesn't look 'bootstrap' at all. I would like to:

- vertically center 'name', 'frags' and 'deaths' items
- make input fields smaller
- fix centering of whole form because as you can see I use workaround by adding some divs to fill up to 12 columns

What would be the best way to fix it? Also, for better explanation I have also created this snippet: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/mQoqO

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a reason you're not using Bootstrap 4?

Comment: I've started coding my thing a while a go and started with bootstrap 3 + glyphicons that comes in that package. Don't wan't to go with bootstrap 4 as it require to rewrite most of my forms, but I don't have time to do it right now.